Equation is moved to the extreme right after upgrading to MathJax v3
I've a personal blog built on minimal-mistakes Jekyll theme. Some of the posts use LaTex parsed by MathJax. I've been using MathJax v2 with the following configuration:
MathJax.Hub.Config({

  showProcessingMessages: false,
     messageStyle: "none",
     tex2jax: {
       inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
       displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
       processEscapes: true
     },
     TeX: {
       MultLineWidth: "100%",
       equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" }
     },
     "HTML-CSS": { fonts: ["Latin-Modern"] }

});

MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
Here's an equation and its output.
$$
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{k} X_{ij}Pr[\text{i and j have the same birthday}]
$$
$$ Pr[\text{i and j have unique birthdays}] = 365/365 * 364/365 $$ ($$ i $$ may have been born on any of the $$ 365 $$ days, and $$ j $$ on any of the remaining $$ 364 $$ days).
$$
\therefore Pr[\text{i and j have the same birthday}] = 1 - \frac{364}{365} = \frac{1}{365} \\
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
  E[X] & = \frac{1}{365} * \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{k} X_{ij} \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (k - i - 1 + 1) \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (k - i) \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * (\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} k - \mathop{\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}} i) \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * (k(k - 1) - (1 + 2 +...+ k - 1)) \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * (k(k - 1) - \frac{k(k - 1)}{2}) \\
   & = \frac{k(k - 1)}{(365 * 2)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$


I upgraded MaxJax to v3, and obtained the v3 configuration using the conversion tool provided by MathJax.
v3 configuration:
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
    displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
    processEscapes: true,
    multlineWidth: "100%",
    tags: "ams"
  },
  options: {
    ignoreHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_ignore',
    processHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_process'
  }
};


As you can see, the equation is moved to the extreme right, and overlaid on top of the text above it. How do I fix this?

I actually upgraded to v4.0.0-beta.7 in order to get better validation, and for the newline support.
As for the problem above, I ended up with the following. Thanks to Davide P. Cervone for looking into the ticket I'd opened on MathJax GitHub repo.
$$
\\ X = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if the pair has the same birthday} \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
\begin{aligned}
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{k} X_{ij}Pr[\text{i and j have the same birthday}]
\end{aligned} \\
Pr[\text{i and j have unique birthdays}] = 365/365 * 364/365 $$ ($$ i $$ may have been born on any of the $$ 365 $$ days, and $$ j $$ on any of the remaining $$ 364 $$ days).
$$\\
\therefore Pr[\text{i and j have the same birthday}] = 1 - \frac{364}{365} = \frac{1}{365}
$$
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
  E[X] & = \frac{1}{365} * \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{k} X_{ij} \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (k - i - 1 + 1) \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (k - i) \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * (\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} k - \mathop{\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}} i) \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * (k(k - 1) - (1 + 2 +...+ k - 1)) \\
   & = \frac{1}{365} * (k(k - 1) - \frac{k(k - 1)}{2}) \\
   & = \frac{k(k - 1)}{(365 * 2)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

The live rendering can be seen on this page from my blog.
